# C# - Querying a selectmany within a select statement for a List within a List

Tags: c#, list, select, linq-to-sql

Basically to give you an idea of the design. I have a list of items that have a one to many relationship to another table. An Item can be assigned to multiple protocols, but also to none. When there is none, it needs to have "Unassigned". The first part works Great and gives me what I need per item. After grouping it, I'm having trouble getting a distinct list of what protocols are assigned to the group. See the code below for what I have thus far:

```
var groupedItems = ctx.Items
    .Where(dk=>itemExpression)
    .Select(dk => new
                  {
                      dk.ItemID,
                      dk.IntItemNumber,
                      ProtocolStr = dk.ItemProtocols.Any() 
                                    ? dk.ItemProtocols.Select(p => p.Protocol.ProtocolName)
                                                      .ToList() 
                                    : new List<string> { "Unassigned" },
                  })
    .GroupBy(d => d.ItemID)
    .Select(d => new CustomClass
                 {
                     ItemID = d.Key,
                     Min = d.Min(dd => dd.IntItemNumber),
                     Max = d.Max(dd => dd.IntItemNumber),
                     ProtocolsStr = String.Join(
                         ",",
                         d.SelectMany(dd=>dd.ProtocolStr.Distinct()).ToList()),
                     OrderQty = d.Count()
                 })
    .ToList()
```

When run, I get an error of: `Could not format node 'ClientQuery' for execution as SQL.`

Basically, I want results like this:

```
            ItemId  Min     Max     OrderQty    Protocols
            1       100005  299998  119797      Unassigned, Protocol1, Protocol2
            2       100003  300000  79799       Unassigned, Protocol2
            3       300029  399999  24795       Protocol1
```

I'm assuming the issue is the selectmany nested in the select.

Comment: Pulling in anonymous types. The end result is actually a class, but i didn't think it was relevant to the problem.

Comment: Well, in the actual code it is grouping by a set of things. The id, a foreign key id, and another foreignkey id, I stripped them out as it isn't relevant to the problem.

Comment: Basically,  the first query is a List of ALL items, the second query is to pull groupings of it by itemID. I guess I named my example poorly. IntItemNumber are the individually numbered items and item ID is a type. I'm grouping it by the type.

Comment: Still looking for help with this. May have to pull all the items into a list first, but the dataset is so large I do NOT want to have to pull that much data when I am just grouping it anyway. Enumerating the item list can pull upwards of 80,000 rows of data and that is just too time consuming.